# Is there a provider/wallet best practice for commandline tools?

Tags: wallets, command-line

For webbrowser based apps interaction with the blockchain is very convenient through browser plugin wallets like Metamask. Those plugins are handling the RPC connection to an Ethereum node as well as the security for the private keys.

Is there something similar for commandline based apps?

I think it would be very inconvenient for users to be required to either run an Ethereum node or have an account with a provider like Infura or Alchemy. Also entering your private key interactively for every transaction seems like a big obstacle.